# tooltip doesn't show in jqtree on the node

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tooltip

I'm trying to open the jquery ui tooltip on hovering over the node element of the jqtree nodes.(root, child, etc.,)
I am confused what i am missing, why it doesn't show when on the node.

```
$('#tree1').find('.jqtree_common').tooltip({
        show: {
            effect: 'slidedown',
            delay: 300
        },
        content: function() {
            $('<div>').append("hello");
        },
        items: '*'
    });
$('#input').tooltip();
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/elkk/mgaummk7/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tooltip for the input should be applied like so:

```
$('input').tooltip();
```

since none of the elements have an id of input. There is no tooltip on the nodes because they have no titles, which are needed for tooltips.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/depperm/ydtv2v11/) with tooltips working on tree.

Comment: how did i miss that for the input tooltip, that's bad of me. However, I don't know why it doesn't work if i hover over the node.

Comment: tooltips do work without titles, I have it working in some instances, but for tree, it's not working.

Comment: the documentation examples at https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/ all use titles for tooltips